# Validate that all rows from INNER JOIN have value

Tags: mysql, join

I have a one-to-many table relation between `table1.id` and `table2.parent_id` and want to select `table1.id` based on `table2.status`.

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.parent_id = table1.id
WHERE table2.status = 1
```

This does pretty much what I want if there is only **one** relation in `table2`. But if there are more rows in `table2` one result may have `status=1` but the other have `status=2`.

What I want is to get a result for `table1.id` **only if all** results in `table2` is of `status=1`.

Example;

```
table1
    id=1, name=row1
    id=2, name=row2

table2
    id=1, parent_id=1, status=1
    id=2, parent_id=1, status=2
    id=3, parent_id=2, status=1
    id=4, parent_id=2, status=1
```

In the example above `table1.id = 1` has 2 relations with different statuses, I don't want this row. `table1.id = 2` however have 2 relations with the same `status=1`, I want this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to check for values in the other table.

This query selects all rows from Table1 that do have matching records in Table2, but none of those have a status different than 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
WHERE -- Check for matching records in Table2.
      EXISTS
         (SELECT 'x' FROM Table2 t2 
          WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.id)
      -- Skip rows that have a status different than 1.
      AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 'x' FROM Table2 t2 
          WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.id
          AND t2.status <> 1)
```

I wasn't sure what you want to have if there is not status in Table2 at all. If you want to return rows from Table1 that don't have any matching rows in Table2, you can just omit the first `EXIST <subselect>` part.